# How can I close my account on Yahoo! Answers?

Tags: account-management, yahoo-answers

Is there any straightforward way to do it? I'd also like to keep the original Yahoo! account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this question](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081224063958AAnFggJ) on Yahoo Answers.

TLDR: You have to delete your questions and answers separately.